# Solving Linear Systems - Criteria for Rank Condition

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

It is well known that for $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times m}$ and $b \in \mathbb{K}^n$ the system
$$ Ax = b $$ 
is solvable if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A \mid b)$.

I suppose, in practice one would just use Gauß-Algorithm. However, is there any criterion for $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A \mid b)$?

Answer (score 1):

$ {\rm rank}( A ) = {\rm rank}( A | b ) $ if and only if $ b $ is in the column space of $ A $.  Is that what you are looking for?

Your question is hard to interpret.

Comment: Hmm, true, I guess it probably doesn‘t go much better than this obvious criterion. And yeah, I like the question to have room for interpretation. Thanks.